# WizardPane : Disable 'Previous' button on a screen

Tags: javafx, wizard, controlsfx

How can I disable the 'Previous' button on my Screen of the ControlsFX `WizardPane`? I am trying it with this method `prev.setDisable(true)` but what I have is `NullPointerException`.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    Wizard wizard = new Wizard();

    WizardPane1 page1 = new WizardPane1();

    WizardPane page2 = new WizardPane();

    WizardPane page3 = new WizardPane() {
        @Override
        public void onEnteringPage(Wizard wizard) {
            Node prev = lookupButton(ButtonType.PREVIOUS);
            prev.setDisable(true);
        }
    };

    page1.setContent(page1.getInit());

    wizard.setFlow(new LinearFlow(page1, page2, page3));
    wizard.showAndWait();

}

public class WizardPane1 extends WizardPane {
      public void initWizard() {}
}
```

Comment: What is Wizard class?

Comment: Hi you can look from this page http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Wizard.html

Comment: What does it print for s.o.println(getButtonTypes()); in onEnteringPage() method?

Comment: Output : [ButtonType [text=Vorheriger, buttonData=BACK_PREVIOUS], ButtonType [text=Nächster, buttonData=NEXT_FORWARD], ButtonType [text=Fertigstellen , buttonData=FINISH], ButtonType [text=Abbrechen, buttonData=CANCEL_CLOSE]]

Comment: My texts are in German (text=....)

Answer (score 1):

This will disable the button.

```
@Override 
public void onEnteringPage( Wizard wizard ) { 
     for ( ButtonType type : getButtonTypes() ) {
         if ( type.getButtonData().equals(ButtonBar.ButtonData.BACK_PREVIOUS) ){
             System.out.println("Found Back button");
             previous_button = (Button) lookupButton( type );
             break;
         }
     }

     Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override 
         public void run() {        
          previous_button.setDisable(true); 
         }
    });       
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. For algorithm clarity, I prefer to use a while instead of a for with break. But it is a cosmetic detail.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but according to source code of `Wizard`, it adds its own "Previous" button, and to lookup it you may need to get the reference exactly to the same `ButtonType` by first looking it up using the `ButtonData`:

```
WizardPane page3 = new WizardPane()
{
    @Override
    public void onEnteringPage( Wizard wizard )
    {
        for ( ButtonType type : getButtonTypes() )
        {
            if ( type.getButtonData().equals(ButtonBar.ButtonData.BACK_PREVIOUS) )
            {
                Node prev = lookupButton( type );
                prev.setDisable( true );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't have a NullPointerException but the button is not disabled.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution and it works :))

```
@Override
public void onEnteringPage(Wizard wizard) {

    ObservableList<ButtonType> list = getButtonTypes();

    for (ButtonType type : list) {
        if (type.getButtonData().equals(ButtonBar.ButtonData.BACK_PREVIOUS)) {
            Node prev = lookupButton(type);
            prev.visibleProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are hiding the button, not disabling it as asked in your question. Beside that it has no difference from the other answer.

Comment: You are right. I have a solution for hidding but not for disabling.